# Failed to load API definition with go-openapi/runtime/middleware

Tags: go, swagger, openapi

I am using golang's `http/net` along with `github.com/go-openapi/runtime/middleware` to explore Swagger within `go`. Using the following code:

```
  func setupAndRunHTTPServer() {
    httpPort := envString("HTTP_PORT", defaultHTTPPort)
    httpAddr := net.JoinHostPort("localhost", httpPort)
    service := planting.NewPlantingService()
    eps := endpoints.NewEndpointSet(*service)
    httpServerMux := transport.NewHTTPHandler(eps)

    // Setup the swagger docs and UI.
    var sh http.Handler = middleware.SwaggerUI(middleware.SwaggerUIOpts{}, nil)
    httpServerMux.Handle("/docs", sh)

    // The HTTP listener mounts the Go kit HTTP handler we created.
    httpListener, err := net.Listen("tcp", httpAddr)
    if err != nil {
      os.Exit(1)
    }

    // Serve using the net/http.ServerMux creaded in transport package.
    err = http.Serve(httpListener, httpServerMux)
    if err != nil {
      os.Exit(2)
    }
    defer httpListener.Close()
  }
```

When I go to `http://localhost:8088/docs` I get the following:

[image]

At first glance it appears to me that the `net/http` library along with the `middleware` cannot find the `swagger.json` file relative to the server root. I have that file located in:

```
matthew.hoggan in ~/go/src/project/root on TemplateServer*
⚡ ls -l ./docs/swagger.json
-rw-r--r--  1 matthew.hoggan  staff  3880 Nov 30 04:47 ./docs/swagger.json
```

My question is, how do I tell the `middleware`, where to find the `swagger.json` situated in the current directory while testing the cloned project prior to deploying it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the source code it appears you need to do the following:

```
var sh http.Handler = middleware.SwaggerUI(middleware.SwaggerUIOpts{SpecURL: "./docs/swagger.json"}, nil)
```

If SpecUrl is not specified it will default to:
`/swagger.json`